# How to find the most common words without delete duplicate?

Tags: python, string, collections

I have a list like the following one:

```
group = [
#Group 1 ('aaa bbbb' the most common words = two words)
['aaaa bbbb nnnn',   #<-- row 1
 'aaaa bbbb oooo',   #<-- row 2
 'aaaa bbbb pppp'],   #<-- row 3

#Group 2 ('hello' the most common word = one word)
['hello Jack   T.',  #<-- row 1
 'hello Ramona D.',  #<-- row 2
 'hello Robert G.'], #<-- row 3

#Group 3 ('yes! go go' the most common words = the whole string)
['yes! go go',      #<-- row 1
 'yes! go go',      #<-- row 2
 'yes! go go',      #<-- row 3     
 'yes! go go'],     #<-- row 4    

#Group 4 (only one word  = it's an invalid group)
['python'],          #<-- row 1 

#Group 5 (only one word = it's an invalid group)
['java']            #<-- row 1
```

]

I need to find the most common words for each group and save them to new list :

like this:

```
OUT : ['aaaa','hello','yes! go go']
```

but the third group has duplicate words -> 'go go' and I need both, so
the real out is :

```
OUT : ['aaaa','hello','yes! go']
```

this is the working code

```
#Try to count words for each group
for groups in group:
    #how many groups ?
    nGroup = len(groups)
    #join lists
    words = " ".join(groups).split()
```

I get:

> ```
> WORDS ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'nnnn', 'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'oooo', 'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'pppp']
> WORDS ['hello', 'Jack', 'T.', 'hello', 'Ramona', 'D.', 'hello', 'Robert', 'G.']
> WORDS ['java']
> WORDS ['python']
> WORDS ['yes!', 'go', 'go', 'yes!', 'go', 'go', 'yes!', 'go', 'go', 'yes!', 'go', 'go']
> ```

```
    #how many identical rows ?
    rows = collections.Counter(words)
    #what's the common words for each row ?
    wCommon = rows.most_common()
    #how often that's?
    mCommon = rows.most_common(1)[0][1]
    print (f"wCommon :{wCommon}  rows :{rows}  mCommon :{mCommon}")
```

I get:

```
#Group 1
wCommon :[('aaaa', 3), ('bbbb', 3),
      ('nnnn', 1), ('oooo', 1),
      ('pppp', 1)]
rows :Counter({'aaaa': 3, 'bbbb': 3,
           'nnnn': 1, 'oooo': 1,
           'pppp': 1})
mCommon :3        


#Group 2
wCommon :[('hello', 3), ('Jack', 1), ('T.', 1),
      ('Ramona', 1), ('D.', 1),
      ('Robert', 1), ('G.', 1)]
rows:Counter({'hello': 3, 'Jack': 1, 'T.': 1,
          'Ramona': 1, 'D.': 1,
          'Robert': 1, 'G.': 1})
mCommon:3


#Group 3
wCommon :[('java', 1)]  rows:Counter({'java': 1})  mCommon:1
#Group 4
wCommon :[('python', 1)]  rows:Counter({'python': 1})  mCommon:1
#Group 5
wCommon :[('go', 8), ('yes!', 4)]  rows:Counter({'go': 8, 'yes!': 4})
mCommon:8
```

the following one is the original list but it can change.
I tried to split it into groups and count the common words for each row...
for example:

> aaaa, hello , yes! go go

but sometimes there are one or more common words like 'aaaa bbbb' How to get it ?
or duplicates like 'go' and in that case it doesn't work

list_1 = [

```
 "aaaa bbbb nnnn",
 "aaaa bbbb oooo",
 "aaaa bbbb pppp",
 "hello Ramona D.",
 "hello Jack   T.",
 "hello Robert G.",
 "yes! go go",
 "yes! go go",
 "yes! go go",
 "yes! go go",
 "python",
 "java"
```

]

Edit:
Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check if multiple words got the same occurrence count and do they appear consecutively:

```
import collections

groups = [
    #Group 1 ('aaa bbbb' the most common words = two words)
    [
        'aaaa bbbb nnnn',  #<-- row 1
        'aaaa bbbb oooo',  #<-- row 2
        'aaaa bbbb pppp'
    ],
    # Group 2 (one word 'aaaa' or 'bbbb', lets take the first)
    ['aaaa nnnn bbbb', 'aaaa oooo bbbb', 'aaaa pppp bbbb'],
    #Group 3 (two words 'oooo bbbb')
    ['aaa1 oooo bbbb', 'aaa2 oooo bbbb', 'aaa3 oooo bbbb'],

    #Group 4 ('hello' the most common word = one word)
    [
        'hello Jack   T.',  #<-- row 1
        'hello Ramona D.',  #<-- row 2
        'hello Robert G.'
    ],  #<-- row 3

    #Group 5 ('yes! go go' the most common words = the whole string)
    [
        'yes! go go',  #<-- row 1
        'yes! go go',  #<-- row 2
        'yes! go go',  #<-- row 3
        'yes! go go'
    ],  #<-- row 4

    #Group 6 (only one word  = it's an invalid group)
    ['python'],  #<-- row 1

    #Group 7 (only one word = it's an invalid group)
    ['java'],
    [
        "yu yu hakusho co dell'altro mondo", "yu yu hakusho re dell'inferno jr",
        'yu yu hakusho un amico per la pelle'
    ],
    [
        "yu yu yu hakusho co dell'altro mondo",
        "yu yu hakusho re dell'inferno jr yu yu",
        'yu yu yu hakusho un amico per la pelle'
    ]
]


def mostCommon(group):
    # skip invalid
    if len(group) < 2:
        return

    # all identical!
    if len(set(group)) == 1:
        return group[0]

    words = " ".join(group).split()
    c = collections.Counter(words)
    _maxCounts = max(c.values())

    # normalize maxCounts, in case maxCounts > length of group
    _maxItems = []
    for k, v in c.items():
        if v >= len(group) or v >= _maxCounts:
            _maxItems.extend([k] * divmod(v, len(group))[0])

    # One word appears most often.
    if len(_maxItems) == 1:
        return _maxItems[0]

    # Multiple words having same max. occurences, do the words appear consecutively ?
    # Lookup reverse, starting with longest
    _combinations = [_maxItems[:x] for x in range(1, len(_maxItems) + 1)]
    print(_combinations)
    for c in _combinations[::-1]:
        if len(set([item
                    for item in group if ' '.join(c) in item])) == len(group):
            return ' '.join(c)


for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    result = mostCommon(group)
    print(f"Group {i+1}: {result}")
```

Out:

```
Group 1: aaaa bbbb
Group 2: aaaa
Group 3: oooo bbbb
Group 4: hello
Group 5: yes! go go
Group 6: None
Group 7: None
Group 8: yu yu hakusho
Group 9: yu yu
```

Comment: good idea about having same max, but here it returns only 'yu' and not 'yu yu hakusho'  [["yu yu hakusho  co dell'altro mondo", "yu yu hakusho  re dell'inferno jr", 'yu yu hakusho  un amico per la pelle']]

Comment: @Francesco: Thanks for pointing that out. Counter sums up all words: `Counter({'yu': 8, 'hakusho': 3, 'co': 1, "dell'altro": 1 ...`, which is fixed now. But, as you can see for Group2 and Group9 always the first wins. Probably `_combinations` should be a real [combination](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) of words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections, re
def most_common(d):
   if len(d) < 2:
      return #invalid group
   groups, _d = [re.split('\s+', i) for i in d], collections.defaultdict(int)
   for i in groups:
       for b in [i[k:j] for j in range(len(i)+1) for k in range(j)]:
          _d[' '.join(b)] += 1
   return max(_d, key=lambda x:(_d[x] > 1, len(x.split()), _d[x]))

group = [['aaaa bbbb nnnn', 'aaaa bbbb oooo', 'aaaa bbbb pppp'], ['hello Jack   T.', 'hello Ramona D.', 'hello Robert G.'], ['yes! go go', 'yes! go go', 'yes! go go', 'yes! go go'], ['python'], ['java']]
print(list(filter(None, map(most_common, group))))
```

Output:

```
['aaaa bbbb', 'hello', 'yes! go go']
```